# Launch an HTML file with Excel

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-runtime

> Please note this is UWP/WinRT.

I have a report generated as `HTML`. It is tabular. I would like to give the user an option to pop this file open in Excel for filtering, sorting and manipulation reasons. [LaunchFileAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-the-default-app-for-a-file) would be a good option, except it opens the `HTML` file with the `default` app: the browser. My goal is to open the `HTML` file with Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to launch an HTML file with Excel, it will launch the default app, so you can use LauncherOptions to launch the Excel that you select from the Open With dialog box.

```
var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
options.DisplayApplicationPicker = true;
bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file, options);
```

Comment: This seems to read it as a TEXT file, though. The formatting is lost.

Comment: If 1) the file extension is `XLS` and 2) includes the `<html />` tags, it works.